# How to create a function and call it in the same script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need help with creating a function in a script and within that same script calling the function. I have tested this code:

```
function FUNC1() {
$source="C:\Folder\file.txt"
$destination="\\Server\folder"
$searchFiles = Get-Content "$source"
foreach($filename in $searchFiles){ 
    Test-Path $destination\$filename 
    }
}

function FUNC2() {
$source="C:\Folder\file.txt"
$destination="\\Server\folder"
$searchFiles = Get-Content "$source"
foreach($filename in $searchFiles){ 
    Move-Item C:\folder\$filename $destination -force
    }
}

if (!(FUNC1)) {FUNC2}
```

However, when testing FUNC1 for false, it does not move anything. When I run the code in the function separately, everything works as it should. Put them together as functions and it is not working. I do not want to create a separate function.ps1 to call, I would rather have my functions called from within the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FUNC1` is going to return an array (of booleans) if `$searchFiles` has two or more filenames in it.

This will always be true, even if it just contains multiple `$false` values (because you're testing the array, not the values it contains). Negating this (the `!`) will always give `$false` so the contents of the `if` will never be executed.

Your approach seems very strange, where perform all the tests and then the moves whatever the tests showed for that file. I would have expected something like:

```
Get-Content "$source" | 
  Where-Object { -not (Test-Path $destination\$_) } |
  Foreach-Object { Move-Item C:\folder\$_ $destination }
```

Which will iterate over all the lines in `$source`, ignore cases where a file of that name exists at the destination and move the file to the destination.

Comment: Richard, Thank you! I am new to this and the way I did it was the only way I knew how to do it. You have given me a better option, that actually works! Will definitely need to read on these commands so I can become more familiar with them. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is confusing, "!(FUNC1)"will always be $false. result of FUNC1 is a varaible(array type), and not $null, will be regard as true, so !(FUNC1) will be $false. You could just combine these two functions into one:

```
function FUNC1() {
    $source="C:\Folder\file.txt"
    $destination="\\Server\folder"

    $searchFiles = Get-Content "$source"
    foreach($filename in $searchFiles){ 
        if(-not (Test-Path $destination\$filename))
        {
            Move-Item C:\folder\$filename $destination -force
        } 
    }
}
```